# Center two divs, with a max-width: 1224px, within a 100% width container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Note:  I am unable to edit the HTML, so I have to find a workaround.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="breadcrumbAds">...</div>
    <div id="breadcrumbWrapper">...</div>
    <div id="containerTopParsys">...</div>
    <div id="leftColWrapper" class="column663Wrapper">...</div>
    <div id="rightColWrapper" class="rightColumn663Wrapper">...</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div id="containerBottomParsys">...</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div id="bgpromo">...</div>
    <div style="clear:both;">...</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

The issue is that all of the divs inside `#container`, EXCEPT for `#leftColWrapper` and `#rightColWrapper`, need to be **100%** width of `#container`, but `#leftColWrapper` and `#rightColWrapper` need to be stacked next to each other and centered (together) within the **100%** `#container`, with a `max-width` of **1224px**.

I tried utilizing the following jQuery to add a wrapper div around `#left`... and `#right`..., but it ended up grabbing the ads in those containers and placing them in the component where the JS for the page is stored.

```
(function($) {
    $("#leftColWrapper, #rightColWrapper").wrapAll("<div class=\"colWrapper\" />");
})(jQuery);
```

I either need another solution to wrap those two divs together, so that I can set a `max-width` of **1224px** and center them, or I need to know why this jQuery is picking up those ads and duplicating them within the JS component.

Answer (score 2):

```css
#container{
text-align: center;
font-size: 0;
}
#container > div{
outline: 1px solid #333;
display: inline-block;
min-height: 10px;
text-align: left;
width: 100%;
font-size: 14px;
}
#container #leftColWrapper, #container #rightColWrapper{
width: 50%;
max-width: 612px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="breadcrumbAds">...</div>
<div id="breadcrumbWrapper">...</div>
<div id="containerTopParsys">...</div>
<div id="leftColWrapper" class="column663Wrapper">width: 50%;<br>
max-width: 612px;</div><div id="rightColWrapper" class="rightColumn663Wrapper">width: 50%;<br>
max-width: 612px;</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id="containerBottomParsys">...</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id="bgpromo">...</div>
<div style="clear:both;">...</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```